# Zero(0) not showing in jsx

Tags: reactjs

Created a state with a default value of `null`

```
const [zero, setZero] = useState(null)
```

If we set the state, via `setZero(0)`, to `0`, the jsx is not showing `0`.

In jsx:

```
{zero ? zero : "No data"}
```

It gives "No data" as a output.

How to show zero value `0` in jsx?

Answer (score 3):

Zero is falsy, so `zero ?` will result in the alternative expression being used, the `No data`. Use the nullish coalescing operator instead.

```
{ zero ?? "No data" }
```

which evaluates to the right-hand side if the left side is `undefined` or `null`.